# What's the principle of atadenoise algorithm and which function in ffmpeg source code implement the atadenoise algorithm?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I cannot figure out which function in libavfilter/vf_atadenoise.c implements atadenoise in ffmpeg...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level function is

```
static int filter_frame(AVFilterLink *inlink, AVFrame *buf)
```

In it, the call

```
ctx->internal->execute(ctx, s->filter_slice, &td, NULL,
                       FFMIN3(s->planeheight[1],
                              s->planeheight[2],
                              ff_filter_get_nb_threads(ctx)));
```

leads to threaded execution of the filtering.

`s->filter_slice` is a function pointer to the actual filtering function depending on input parameters.

Referencing to the function pointer happens in

```
static int config_input(AVFilterLink *inlink)
```

All the bespoke filter functions are defined using macros starting at the line which says,

```
#define WFILTER_ROW(type, name)
```

Comment: thx for your answer. Now I'm trying to debug ffmpeg-atadenoise in Xcode.

Comment: Could you please help me transplant atadenoise in ffmepg to my own project?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459547/how-to-connect-ffmpegs-atadenoise-to-my-own-project